# Hiding <tr> that contain a variable in the id's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to select all the tr's that have id's that contain a variable.
It's supposed to hide elements that don't match as the user types into the search form.
The form has an id of #search.

```
$(function () {
      var content = $('#search').val();
      $('#search').keyup(function () {
          if ($('#search').text() != content) {
              content = $('#search').val();
              //content has changed, do stuff
              if (!$('tr.id:contains(content)')) {
                  $('this').hide();
              }
          }
      });
  });
```

Comment: That's not what `:contains` does. It looks at the contents of the element, not the contents of the "id" value.

Comment: Also, it's $(this).hide(), not $('this').hide()

Comment: $(this) may be out of scope unless you capture it immediately after your keyup funciton.  Example: var srchthis = this;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$('tr[id*=' + content + ']').hide();
```

The `*=` thing in an attribute match clause says to match any tag that's got the indicated attribute with a value that contains the substring on the right, which I think is exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: For reference, that's the [Attribute Contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Comment: Thanks - I'm pretty bad with terminology :-)

Comment: I wanted it to list the contents of the table until i start typing also. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: @Marisa well I'm not sure; perhaps you could explain that more thoroughly in a new question.